References for Rigorous Convergence and Error Analysis of root finding methods
Many numerical analysis books illustrate the regula falsi method, Newton-Raphson, and secant methods with examples and illustrations but often omit rigorous convergence analysis.
For example, illustrations (diagrams) of the Newton-Raphson and secant methods frequently assume convexity of the function, giving the impression that successive iterates are monotonic. However, convergence theorems generally require only $f'(p) > 0$, not $f''(p) > 0$. Additionally, it is not explicitly mentioned why the regula falsi method converges and why the iterates do not oscillate between successive values.
Could anyone suggest references (books or online notes) that provide a rigorous convergence and error analysis of these methods?

Iterative Methods for Linear and Nonlinear Equations by Kelley satisfies these criteria
